# Xcode not finishing archiving on "validate *.app" step

Tags: objective-c, xcode, validation, archive

So I am running xcode 4.6 trying and trying to make a release archive for an iPad app. Unfortunately, when I hit Product>Archive, XCode will not finish the archive. When i go into the logs, it gets all the way through the code sign step and just hangs on "validate Finger-Spelling.app" (It is an ASL app)

It had the same issue earlier, but it fixed it when I updated to xcode 4.6. Honestly, I probably have just forgotten something simple, so I here are is the build log for the step it is stuck on.

The build log step that it is stuck on:

```
Validate /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Finger-Spelling-dfbrlachhucwlcamnxjofkjuekbi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Finger-Spelling/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Finger-Spelling.app
    cd "/Users/Michael/Documents/Xcode Projects/Finger-Spelling"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Finger-Spelling-dfbrlachhucwlcamnxjofkjuekbi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Finger-Spelling/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Finger-Spelling.app
```

It also may be my Bundle ID, which is "com.MichaelB.Finger-Spelling", but that matches up with everything in my info.plists.

Answer (score 0):

really a stab in the dark but when I had a problem here it was that the version number I had entered was incorrect.